# How to make my backend restful api address configureable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I'm creating a flutter application consuming some backend restful apis(eg., `http://api.myserver.com`, also created by me).

Since I'm new to flutter, I don't know how to make the backend address(eg., `http://api.myserver.com`) configureable in my flutter side. what's the best practice here? Could anybody direct me to some references on this topic?

Currently I hard-code it in my flutter code. It's bad since every time I change my server address, I've to change and re-compile my flutter code. This flutter app is target both on web and mobile(ie., iOS and andriod).

Comment: use some local cache like SharedPreference to save the base url. you can use a page for selecting url on the app start, and save the url on pref.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this
first, i create a class with base URL

```
class RoutingBase {
  static const ApiUrl = "https://copserver.dina.....org/api/v1";
}
```

then for every different base Api, i create a class too

```
 class RoutingBalance extends RoutingBase{
  static const BaseName = "Balance";
  
  static const GET_Home = "${RoutingBase.ApiUrl}/$BaseName/Home";
  static const GET_Search = "${RoutingBase.ApiUrl}/$BaseName/Search";
  static const GET_QuickSearch = "${RoutingBase.ApiUrl}/$BaseName/QuickSearch";
  static const GET_ShowCategory = "${RoutingBase.ApiUrl}/$BaseName/ShowCategory";
  static const GET_ShowAllParents = "${RoutingBase.ApiUrl}/$BaseName/ShowAllParents";
}
```

and i can access it like this

```
RoutingBalance.GET_Home,
```

In this way, i could handle all URL of a very big app with just a few class and change them very easy

Comment: Yes but you still have `RoutingBalance` having all those values almost hardcoded (due to using `const`). Maybe if you will have a different subclass of `RoutingBase` for every host and able to switch them...then that might be closer to what was asked.

Comment: @Alex That is a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter way**

One way is to have a (Flutter) setup screen from where to pick the base endpoint you want to use. It has to be both accessible without an API call and it has to be limited in the options it offers (ex: a drop down with desired host endpoints) to avoid exploits and reverse engineering of your API calls.

**Back-end/sysadmin way**

Another way is to "fake it" and here there are a few options:

1. Keep same domain as endpoint but make it point to different IP (Ex: under *nix change the entries in /etc/hosts file)
2. Use a proxy on the endpoint that will simply forward calls to whatever new server you have. (Ex: You always connect to foo.com/api but the app from foo.com/api will forward calls to wherever is needed)